# dplyr mutate using conditional column and specific rows

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I have a data.frame with two score columns. I want to conditionally use data from one of them on a per-row basis. I explain with an example below...

```
> dff <- data.frame(dataset = c('Main','Main','b','b','c','c','d','d'), 
+                  score1 = c(0.01,0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08), 
+                  score2 = c(0.001, 0.2, 0.003, 0.4, 0.005, 0.6, 0.007, 0.8),
+                  name = c('A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B')); 
> dff
  dataset score1 score2 name
1    Main   0.01  0.001    A
2    Main   0.02  0.200    B
3       b   0.03  0.003    A
4       b   0.04  0.400    B
5       c   0.05  0.005    A
6       c   0.06  0.600    B
7       d   0.07  0.007    A
8       d   0.08  0.800    B
```

I am trying to select all the values from one score for all rows for which `name == 'A'`, and similar for `name == 'B'`. Which score I choose depends on which score is lesser when `dataset == 'Main'`.

So for example, in this example, when `name == 'A'`, `score2` is lower than `score1` for the `Main` dataset. Thus, for all the rows where `name == 'A'`, I will use their value from `score2`.

When `name == 'B'`, `score1` is lower than `score2` for the `Main` dataset. Thus, for all the rows where `name == 'B'`, I will use their value from `score1`. The final result would look like this:

```
  dataset score1 score2 name final
1    Main   0.01  0.001    A 0.001
2    Main   0.02  0.200    B 0.020
3       b   0.03  0.003    A 0.003
4       b   0.04  0.400    B 0.040
5       c   0.05  0.005    A 0.005
6       c   0.06  0.600    B 0.060
7       d   0.07  0.007    A 0.007
8       d   0.08  0.800    B 0.080
```

So what I am trying to do is conditionally mutate and create the new `final` column depending on both what the name is for that row, and which column was lesser for the `Main` dataset with that same name. I'm trying to think of something elegant to accomplish this and not a bunch of weird lines of code, but I haven't been able to accomplish that yet.

EDIT: 
I'm including a sample of my actual data here.

```
structure(list(datasets = c("main", "main", "bms", "bms", "sny", 
"sny", "chen", "chen", "van", "van"), test_high = c(0.639654382299527, 
0.561881930194033, NA, NA, 0.909598942079794, 0.651429614317738, 
0.189274551669056, 0.541845226349475, 0.41969855766237, 0.555858598773613
), test_low = c(0.402779917451124, 0.469868712458501, NA, NA, 
0.106383376175001, 0.381060050671353, 0.824427629626441, 0.468590829264603, 
0.594646024750062, 0.460036802365713), cell = c("high", "low", 
"low", "high", "high", "low", "high", "low", "low", "high")), .Names = c("datasets", 
"test_high", "test_low", "cell"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))


   # A tibble: 10 x 4
   datasets test_high  test_low  cell
      <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>
 1     main 0.6396544 0.4027799  high
 2     main 0.5618819 0.4698687   low
 3      bms        NA        NA   low
 4      bms        NA        NA  high
 5      sny 0.9095989 0.1063834  high
 6      sny 0.6514296 0.3810601   low
 7     chen 0.1892746 0.8244276  high
 8     chen 0.5418452 0.4685908   low
 9      van 0.4196986 0.5946460   low
10      van 0.5558586 0.4600368  high
```

Final in this case would end up being the same as test_low because for both Mains (ie when cell is 'high', and cell is 'low') the test_low column is smaller than the test_high column.

Comment: in the edit, what would be the expected output column.  Looks like for `main` the 'test_high' is higher for 'high' and 'low'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
dff %>%
    mutate(final =  case_when(name == "A" & dataset == "Main" ~ score2,
                       name == "B" & dataset=="Main" ~score1, 
                       TRUE ~ pmin(score1, score2)))
#  dataset score1 score2 name final
#1    Main   0.01  0.001    A 0.001
#2    Main   0.02  0.200    B 0.020
#3       b   0.03  0.003    A 0.003
#4       b   0.04  0.400    B 0.040
#5       c   0.05  0.005    A 0.005
#6       c   0.06  0.600    B 0.060
#7       d   0.07  0.007    A 0.007
#8       d   0.08  0.800    B 0.080
```

---

Based on the edited dataset ('dfn'),

```
dfn %>%
     filter(datasets == "main") %>% 
     gather(test, val, test_high:test_low) %>% 
     group_by(cell) %>% 
     summarise(test = test[which.max(val)]) %>% 
     left_join(dfn, .) %>%
     rowwise() %>% 
     mutate(final = get(test)) %>%
     select(-test)
```

Comment: Right but the trouble with this is that which column is used should depend on the values for when dataset == 'Main'. So sometimes I may have both score1 and score1, or both score2 and score2, etc.

Comment: @Brandon I added the `Main` also in the logic

Comment: Ah I see what this logic is doing. I would need to adjust this so that the other rows are using the information from when dataset == "Main". So something that started like this: case_when(name == "A" & dataset == "Main" ~ pmin(score1, score2), name == "B" & dataset == "Main" ~ pmin(score1, score2), name == "A" ~ {use whatever column was the min for when name =="A" and dataset =="Main"}, name == "B" ~ {use whatever column was the min for when name =="B" and dataset =="Main"}). 

Does this make sense?

Comment: @Brandon I think your example is kind of creating confusion.  Could you make another example that gives a unique output instead of just doing some `ifelse` and getting the expected output

Comment: @Brandon I updated with a solution.  Please check if that is what you expected

Answer (score 0):

```
dff$final <- ifelse(dff$score2 < dff$score1 & dff$dataset == 'Main', dff$score2, dff$score1)
```

[image]